# I recommend vs. I would recommend

Tags: verbs, tenses, conditionals

I just realized that throughout my life I have interchanged "I recommend that you do X" and "I would recommend that you do X".

Is there a difference in their meanings in modern-day usage, or are they functionally the same?

Comment: Adding *would* simply makes it more polite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My experience is that "would" makes the verb feel a little tentative.  I tend to use the construct when I'm not sure of my reception.  So "I would recommend" gets used when I'm not sure if the person wants a recommendation.

Comment: I agree. I think the use of "would" contains an implied condition along the lines of "[If you asked for my opinion] I would recommend.." and is used when you want to offer your opinion but have not been expressly asked, or your role is junior to that of the receiver of the recommendation. Or perhaps also where there is some other implied condition that is unspoken, e.g. "[If we only have the budget for a cheaper model then] I would recommend this...". But the nuance is slight and I expect there is plenty of evidence "would" is often used in non-conditional circumstances these days as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the "would" form indicates a (missing) condition or qualification on your recommendation:

```
I would recommend that you do X, but I can't because of Y.
```

The form without "would" is unconditional.

Comment: This maybe isn't the best answer, but what's so bad about it that it's worth down-voting?

Comment: @stewSquared: Agreed!  I thought it was looking like 2.2 here: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/would  "Warnock admitted it would be the ideal scenario **if** he received a Carling Cup winners' medal as well as an England call-up"

Answer (score -1):

"I would recommend," seems to imply that the recommendee(?) take a certain action:

"I would recommend the Sony TV." (The person being spoken to is trying to choose a purchase -and the speaker is trying to help/persuade the action.)

"I would recommend that you buckle your seat belt." (A bit more forceful - perhaps ominous - but again, trying to help/persuade the action.)

"I recommend the chocolate mousse." This is *softer*(?), maybe even a non-sequitur to indicate that the chocolate mousse was yummy.

Comment: No, it’s for politeness.

Comment: @tchrist As a native speaker for half a century, I'm not buying that.

Comment: @tchrist "May I recommend the lobster bisque," and "If I may, I WOULD recommend the lobster bisque," are equally polite, but I would infer from the first that the lobster bisque was excellent that night, and from the second that somebody put too much salt in the clam chowder.